# ProGuard with Gradle application plugin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, proguard, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am currently trying to minimize the output of a (non-android) kotlin application, which is being created with the [gradle application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html). Specifically with the `./gradlew installDist` or `./gradlew distZip` task.
Now I want to apply ProGuard for minimization and obfuscation, and have used [ProGuards example](https://github.com/Guardsquare/proguard/blob/master/examples/application-kotlin/build.gradle) for setting it up with the application plugin. I had to convert this to Gradle Kotlin DSL, but am not sure about its validity, because I receive a lot of warning when running the ProGuard task, which lead me to believe that something is not set up correctly:

```
Warning: there were 920 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning: there were 39 unresolved references to program class members.
```

The task:

```
tasks.register<ProGuardTask>("proguard") {
    configuration("proguard.pro")
    verbose()
    printconfiguration("$buildDir/proguard/configuration.txt")
    printseeds("$buildDir/proguard/seeds.txt")

    injars(tasks.distZip)
    outjars("$buildDir/distributions/minified.zip")

    libraryjars(
        mapOf(
            "jarfilter" to "!**.jar",
            "filter" to "!module-info.class",
        ),
        "${System.getProperty("java.home")}/jmods/java.base.jmod",
    )
    libraryjars(sourceSets["main"].compileClasspath)
}
```

`proguard.pro` file

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature,InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod

-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }

# Entry point to the app.
-keep class com.foo.bar.MainKt { *; }

-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn javax.swing.**

# https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2046
-dontwarn java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer
-dontwarn sun.misc.SignalHandler
-dontwarn java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation
-dontwarn sun.misc.Signal
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? It looks like you have this running, but you're concerned about whether or not this works. Have you tested it? Is it obfuscated? Does it run without crashing? I'm not sure what the ask is here.

Comment: I cannot verify that it works because the warnings I receive cause the task to be aborted and no artifact is built. But your question leads me to believe that ProGuard is in fact setup correctly, but I need to configure it properly.